# Finding the standard matrix of linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

This is similar to one of my other questions.

Question:

Let $T$ be a linear operator in $\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^4$ such that

$T\begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},T\begin{pmatrix}3\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix} = 0,T\begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\1\\1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1\\2\\1\\1\end{pmatrix},T\begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\-1\\-2\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-2\\0\\1\\2\end{pmatrix}$

Find the standard matrix of the linear operator T

I'm also not sure where to start with this one, any help appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: The information you are given is the same as saying that $(2,1,0,0)^\top, (3,1,0,0)^\top, (1,2,1,1)^\top$ and $(2, 0, -1, -2)^\top$ are eigenvectors of $T$ with eigenvalues $1, 0, 1$ and $-1$ respectively. Then the standard matrix representation of $T$ is similar to the diagonal matrix $D = \text{diag}(1, 0, 1, -1)$.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to answer this without the use of eigenvectors and eigenvalues?

Comment: Definitely, but I think that is the most straight-forward way here. How much do you know about change of bases?

Comment: Not a lot I don't think...

Comment: Well, then this will perhaps be a lot of work, but what you can do is to set up a system of equations so that you based on the information you have, can determine what $T$ does to the standard basis vectors for $\mathbb{R}^4$ and then the matrix you are looking for has these vectors as its columns. To me this looks like a strange exercise to give if you have neither worked with diagonalization and eigenvectors nor change of bases.